# Embedding a tiny .swf file stored as a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, security, flash, browser, actionscript

Is there any way of embedding a .swf file from a string?

Here's the scenario:

1. I have a tiny .swf file I want to load into the page dynamically using JavaScript.  It's less than 1kb.
2. Rather than making a round-trip to the network, I could store the contents of the .swf file as a string in JavaScript
3. If I have such a string in JavaScript, is there any way to inject the string into an embed tag, such that the .swf file loads normally?

This technique works for storing small .svg images for icons and embedding them directly into .css files.  Is this possible for Flash?  Or are there security issues that would prevent this?

Comment: Does a data url work for this?

Comment: The only way JavaScript supports loading external resources like this is through Data URIs *or* Blob URIs. These URIs are effectively treated as external resources and can be used in the relevant 'src' attributes.

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers, you can't, because they don't allow the inclusion of active content in `<object>` and `<embed>` tags via `data:` URIs.

For instance, something like this wouldn't work:

```
<html>
<body>
    <embed id="flash" width="200" height="200" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></div>

    <script>
      var flashData = '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';

      var flashObject = document.getElementById('flash');
      flashObject.src = 'data:application/x-shockwave-flash;base64,' + flashData;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are not joking that this wont work... It skips the whole "embedding a plugin into an html page" thing. I think they have to edit some lines in a tool like [swfObject.js](https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject) file to tell it to expect embedded data instead of filename.